# Error when compiling code

Tags: c++, printf, declaration

I am getting this error ***string undeclared*** while compiling this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
string names;
printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%s", &names);

printf("Your name is %s", names);
return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me why. Many thanks

Comment: Include the `string` header. And add `std` like @taocp said.

Comment: Also, `printf` is a C function that has no knowledge of streams.  Use `cin` and `cout` instead of the old C functions.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Answer (score 8):

you should include string header:

```
#include <string>
```

and don't forget namespace `std` when using it:

```
std::string names;
```

Besides, don't mix C and C++ when you code. Try to use `std::cout` not `printf`, `cin/getline` not `scanf`.

Comment: In particular, passing `std::string` object (names in this case) as an argument to `printf` will definitely not work as expected.

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's another great point I overlooked. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
#include <string>
```

to reference string from the C++ standard library and state that you're using std with

```
using namespace std;
```

See [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++StringClass.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing C++, then the standard string class is called `std::string`, and is in the header `<string>`. But you wouldn't usually want to use `printf` or `scanf` with it, you'd use C++ I/O:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string names;
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    getline(cin, names);
    cout << "Your name is " << names << endl;
}
```

If (despite the question tag) you're writing C, then there is no type called `string`. Strings are conventionally represented by arrays of characters:

```
char names[SOME_LARGE_NUMBER];
```

but beware that, unless you're very careful, `scanf` could overrun the buffer and cause all manner of runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because std::string is defined in the header string, which you have not included, and because its full and proper name is std::string, not just string.